# PHP JSON format object

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

PHP Noob here...

```
if i have JSON format: {"0":"0x1001C","1":"0"}
but what i really want is is: {"0x1001C","0"}
```

how do i attain this?

esentially, i have an array which contains keys and values. 
i'm removing the keys (as this is a requrement) and the final array must be in object format (in other words, JSON has to return something with {} rather than [] )

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you _have_ an object (`{}` rather than `[]`), you want to convert it to an array and then back to an object??? What you want (`{"foo","bar"}`) is invalid JSON. `{}` will always show key-value pairs, `[]` won't, there's no in-between.

Comment: ok, phew, good to know, i tried everything to put it in this format and i just couldn't figure out a solution on my own. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 echo json_encode(array('0x1001c', '0'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as per the docs: http://php.net/json_encode